# How can we know if User still active with VUE/Django/JWT?

Tags: django, vue.js, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

Currently I use rest_framework_jwt to manage the authentication process, Checked the doc [Django REST framework JWT refresh-token](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/?#refresh-token) I find this sentence below,

> Each time the user **loads the page**, you can check if there is an
> existing non-expired token and if it's close to being expired, refresh
> it to extend their session. In other words, if a **user is actively**
> using your site, they can **keep their "session" alive**.

My query is,

1. How to know user still active?
2. Could we extend this "active" status infinitely? It looks maximum refresh time is: 'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA' + 'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA'

**Configuration:** Frontend: VUE; Backend: Django; Backend API: DRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. When user logs in, user + password get sent to server and once validated, a token is generated and stored on server as well as sent back to client.
2. Client once receives the token, store it in local storage.
3. From then on, each time user make a request to server, attach the token to the request. On the server side, check for token in the incoming request and validate it against it with what server already is having.
4. If token is valid, perform the backend process.

However, a token should be generally short-lived (a few hours). This in general should come with a “refresh token”, a refresh token is used to refresh the access token and generally long-lived (a few months).

Comment: Thanks Kelvin for your suggestions. One question here, "each time user make a request to server", is there some better solution than "each time"? Besides this, maybe some user activity don't need "Auth", do they need still send token?

Comment: Hi Kumar, for those endpoints that need to be protected, authentication needs to happen each time a request is made. Because backend needs to make sure that the request is valid from an authenticated user. There are also endpoints that are open to anonymous requests, for those ones, there’s no need to check for token. So from Django, for each API, you may want to validate with some pre-defined permission: is_anonymous, is_valid_user, is_admin, etc.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. Do you think we'd better trigger "refreshToken" from frontend or backend?

Comment: refresh token is used to get a new access token (vs access token is used to get resources). in most of the cases, access token will carry a expiry date as well, so from frontend, Vue.js app will check if access token is expired, if expired, it will use refresh token to retrieve a new access token - this process is normally done silently. if the process fails (because refresh token is also expired and hence, can't get a new access token), user is then required to log in again.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, since currently my reputation less than 15, so cannot votes, pls understand. "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."